# Optimizing Python code for Project Euler #5 (LCM of all numbers from 1 to 20)

Tags: python, optimization, project-euler

This is my solution for the [5th problem of Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=5), which asks for the least common multiples of the numbers from 1 to 20 (inclusive). Is there any way to improve the while loop conditional instead of using the sum?

```
table = range(1, 21)
result = 1
pf = 2
while sum(table) > len(table):
   flag = False
   for x, y in enumerate(table):
      if y % pf == 0:
         table[x] = y/pf 
         flag = True
   if flag:
      result *= pf
   else:
      pf += 1
print result
```

Comment: are you interested in a functional solution without loops?

Comment: Nah I I know that it's possible to do the same using gcd and reduce, I just want to see how to better optimize this certain algorithm which is basically a pencil and paper algorithm designed for humams. Usually this ends when all elements become 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intent is to terminate the loop when all entries in `table` become 1. This

```
while sum(table) > len(table):
```

is a rather obscure way of expressing that intent. I suggest instead

```
while max(table) > 1:
```

or the more explicit and short-circuiting

```
while any(x > 1 for x in table):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a constant. It's easier to understand when you want to go back and try a different value too.

Copying my answer from stack overflow, also changed things around since this is code review.

```
MAX_FACTOR = 20 #The largest divisor we want to be able to divide by

#should have a general outline of the algorithm here
table = range(1,MAX_FACTOR + 1)
result = 1 #final result is stored here
currentFactor = 2 #what we're currently trying to divide by
while currentFactor <= MAX_FACTOR:
   isDivisor = False #is the currentFactor a divisor
   for x,y in enumerate(table):
      if y % currentFactor == 0:
     table[x] = y/currentFactor 
     isDivisor = True
   if isDivisor:
      result *= currentFactor
   else:
      currentFactor += 1
print result
```